# How to append data to json file in python?

Tags: python, json, string, list, append

I have a json file with these data inside:

```json
[
  {
    "t1": 62.000000,
    "t2": 26.200001,
    "Ir": 100
  },
  {
    "t1": 62.000000,
    "t2": 26.200001,
    "Ir": 100
  },
  {
    "t1": 63.000000,
    "t2": 26.200001,
    "Ir": 100
  }
]
```

Then on my python code, i read it with these command:

```py
with open("data.json", 'r+') as file:
    old_data_list = json.load(file)
```

The type of old_data_list is `<class 'list'>`

So I want to append some data to this list. I receive the data from a ESP32 and then a read it with this command:

```py
data = message.payload.decode('utf-8') # turn bytes to string
```

When i try to append the data to the json file, that's what i get:

```json
[
  {
    "t1": 62.000000,
    "t2": 26.200001,
    "Ir": 100
  },
  {
    "t1": 62.000000,
    "t2": 26.200001,
    "Ir": 100
  },
  {
    "t1": 63.000000,
    "t2": 26.200001,
    "Ir": 100
  },"{"t1":64.000000,"t2":25.799999,"Ir":100}"
]
```

But what i want is:

```json
[
  {
    "t1": 62.000000,
    "t2": 26.200001,
    "Ir": 100
  },
  {
    "t1": 62.000000,
    "t2": 26.200001,
    "Ir": 100
  },
  {
    "t1": 63.000000,
    "t2": 26.200001,
    "Ir": 100
  },
  {
    "t1": 64.000000,
    "t2": 25.799999,
    "Ir": 100
  },
]
```

Comment: I don't believe that you got what you claim you got. Include the code that allegedly does that.

Comment: And also show what `data` is.

Answer (score 0):

Python does the right thing as `data` is a string, not a dictionary. Try:

```py
data = json.loads(message.payload.decode('utf-8'))
```